How do I center this table?
When i add tablenotes to my tabular \centering stops working and the table in placed on the left. I have tried using \begin{center} and adjustbox without success
    \begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\caption{Profilo emodinamico prima e dopo intervento di denervazione renale}\label{tab:profilo emod }
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}\toprule
&prima &dopo &delta &p value* \\\cmidrule{2-5}
\textbf{PAS media} & & & & \\
Prevenzione primaria &157±18 &133±8 &25±20 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Prevenzione secondaria &555±20 &555±19 &18±22 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Totale &555±19 &555±16 &20±21 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
\textbf{PAD media} & & & & \\
Prevenzione primaria &55±12 &55±9 &4±8 &0.2 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Prevenzione secondaria &55±17 &55±11 &3±10 &0.2 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Totale &55±15 &55±10 &3±9 &0.2 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
\textbf{PAM} & & & & \\
Prevenzione primaria &555±10 &555±9 &11±9 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Prevenzione secondaria &555±14 &555±13 &8±8 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Totale &555±13 &55±12 &9±8 &<0,001 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
\textbf{Frequenza cardiaca} & & & & \\
Prevenzione primaria &66±11 &71±13 &-4±19 &0.546 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Prevenzione secondaria &76±16 &75±16 &3±11 &0.546 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Totale &72±15 &73±15 &0±15 &0.546 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
\textbf{Doppio prodotto} & & & & \\
Prevenzione primaria &55555±2160 &55555±2583 &5555±4342 &0.041 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Prevenzione secondaria &5555±2629 &5555±2118 55555±2485 &0.041 \\\cmidrule{1-5}
Totale &5555±2448 &5555±2218 &5555±3263 &0.041 \\\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item * test di Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}


please always provide an example that shows the problem, the table will center if it fits in the space available but the space availabel depends on the page size an dother factors and the size of the table depends on the fonts used, none of which is shown in a fragment, also it makes it harder for people to test answers if they have to guess the definitions of non standard environments and commands such as tablenotes and \bottomrule

this war actually very helpful. tablenotes is part of the threeparttapble package that i wansn't using in the tabular. by writing the correct code the problem was solved

Glad you got it fixed if you get any error you should not look at the pdf output, and if you want to ask a question ask about the error message not ask about the output. You must have had an error telling you tablenotes  is undefined.

I’m voting to close this question because due to missing code not shown in the question, and fixed in comments

In addition to loading the threeparttable package, you may want to strive giving your table a more open and inviting "look". This could be done most effectively by getting rid of most \cmidrule directives. I can also see no reason for rendering the table in \scriptsize. Incidentally, do note that the table has 5 columns, not 6.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % automatic math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
%\centering <-- not needed
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out optimal amount of intercolumn whitespace

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Profilo emodinamico prima e dopo intervento di denervazione renale}
\label{tab:profilo emod }

%\scriptsize % <-- why??

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lRRRR}
\toprule
&\textnormal{prima} &\textnormal{dopo} & \Delta \ \ \  & \textnormal{$p$-value}\tnote{*} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
\textbf{PAS media} \\
Prevenzione primaria   &157\pm 18 &133\pm 8  &25\pm 20 &<0,001 \\
Prevenzione secondaria &555\pm 20 &555\pm 19 &18\pm 22 &<0,001 \\
Totale                 &555\pm 19 &555\pm 16 &20\pm 21 &<0,001 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{PAD media}     \\
Prevenzione primaria   &55\pm 12 &55\pm 9  &4\pm 8  &0.2 \\
Prevenzione secondaria &55\pm 17 &55\pm 11 &3\pm 10 &0.2 \\
Totale                 &55\pm 15 &55\pm 10 &3\pm 9  &0.2 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{PAM} \\
Prevenzione primaria   &555\pm 10 &555\pm 9  &11\pm 9 &<0,001 \\
Prevenzione secondaria &555\pm 14 &555\pm 13 & 8\pm 8 &<0,001 \\
Totale                 &555\pm 13 &55\pm 12  & 9\pm 8 &<0,001 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Frequenza cardiaca} \\
Prevenzione primaria   &66\pm 11 &71\pm 13 &-4\pm 19 &0.546 \\
Prevenzione secondaria &76\pm 16 &75\pm 16 & 3\pm 11 &0.546 \\
Totale                 &72\pm 15 &73\pm 15 & 0\pm 15 &0.546 \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Doppio prodotto} \\
Prevenzione primaria   &55555\pm 2160 &55555\pm 2583 & 5555\pm 4342  & 0.041 \\
Prevenzione secondaria &5555\pm 2629  &5555\pm 2118  & 55555\pm 2485 & 0.041 \\
Totale                 &5555\pm 2448  &5555\pm 2218  & 5555\pm 3263  & 0.041 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip\small
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] test di Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney.
\end{tablenotes}
    
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}


You bit me for 2 minutes :-), +1

With talltblr which is tabularray package equivalent to threeparttable and use siunitx for writig numbers in table body:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htp]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-align-uncertainty = false,
         }
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Profilo emodinamico prima e dopo intervento di denervazione renale},
  label = {tab:profilo emod},
note{*} = {test di Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney.}
                ]{colsep  = 3pt,
                  colspec = {l 
                             *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=5(4)}]}
                                  Q[c, si={table-format=<0.3}]
                             },
                  row{1}  = {guard, mode=text}
                 }
    \toprule
            & prima     & dopo      & delta     & p value\TblrNote{*}   \\
    \midrule
\textbf{PAS media}  
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Prevenzione primaria 
            & 157(18)   & 133(8)    & 25(20)    & <0,001    \\
Prevenzione secondaria 
            & 555(20)   & 555(19)   & 18(22)     & <0,001    \\
    \midrule
Totale      & 555(19)   & 555(16)   & 20(21)     & <0,001    \\    
    \midrule
\textbf{PAD media} 
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Prevenzione primaria 
            & 55(12)    & 55(9)     & 4(8)      & 0.2       \\
Prevenzione secondaria 
            & 55(17)    & 55(11)    & 3(10)     & 0.2       \\
Totale      & 55(15)    & 55(10)    & 3(9)      & 0.2       \\
    \midrule
\textbf{PAM} 
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Prevenzione primaria 
            & 555(10)   & 555(9)    & 11(9)     & <0,001    \\
Prevenzione secondaria 
            & 555(14)   & 555(13)   & 8(8)      & <0,001    \\
    \midrule
Totale      & 555(13)   & 55(12)    & 9(8)      & <0,001    \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Frequenza cardiaca} 
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Prevenzione primaria 
            & 66(11)    & 71(13)    & -4(19)    & 0.546     \\
Prevenzione secondaria 
            & 76(16)    & 75(16)    & 3(11)     & 0.546     \\
    \midrule
Totale      & 72(15)    & 73(15)    & 0(15)     & 0.546     \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Doppio prodotto} 
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Prevenzione primaria 
            & 55555(2160)   
                        & 55555(2583)
                                    & 5555(4342)
                                                & 0.041     \\
Prevenzione secondaria 
    & 5555(2629)
            & 5555(2118)
                    & 55555(2485)
                                & 0.041                 \\
    \midrule
Totale 
    & 5555(2448)
            & 5555(2218)
                    & 5555(3263)
                                & 0.041                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


+1 for nice use of the siunitx machinery.
